# List forked repositories for an organisation

Tags: github-api

Using the Git API, I would like to list the repositories of an organization that were forked from other repositories.

I'm trying:

```
curl https://api.github.com/orgs/camptocamp/repos?type=forks
```

but it only returns 30 repositories, while the `forks` tab in https://github.com/camptocamp/ contains many more… Is there a way to retrieve this list programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is response paging: http://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination.

> Requests that return multiple items will be paginated to 30 items by default. You can specify further pages with the ?page parameter. For some resources, you can also set a custom page size up to 100 with the ?per_page parameter.

When you request `https://api.github.com/orgs/camptocamp/repos?type=forks`, the response headers include a `Link` header that gives you the URL to fetch the next page and the last page:

`Link: <https://api.github.com/organizations/28109/repos?page=2&type=forks>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/organizations/28109/repos?page=6&type=forks>; rel="last"`

Comment: Thanks. I found that I can also send `per_page`, up to 100.